# How to call a stored procedure in CodeIgniter USING SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I'm bulding my application using Codeigniter and SQL server as my database (I am using the SQLSRV PHP extension to connect to SQL ). The problem happens when I try to call Stored Procedures:

```
$query = $this->db->query(
          "EXECUTE verificacion_fechas '".$codigo."',".$estado.",'".$llave_maestra."','".$fecha_actual."'");
```

---

Another way I have tried to create the query with less data is the following , however, it is generating an error:

```
Error Number: 01000 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ejecutando SQL directamente, sin cursor. EXECUTE provando15 34,2,'key05','2015-07-22'
```

I dont really know what im doing wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Can you structure your question, 1) ISSUE, 2) CODE, 3) ERROR, 4)GOAL?

Comment: sorry, my question is for an error

Comment: this is my consult :::::::  $query=$this->db->query("EXECUTE verificacion_fechas('".$codigo."',".$estado.",'".$llave_maestra."','".$fecha_actual."')");   and this is my error   ::::::::::::::  Error Number: 01000

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ejecutando SQL directamente, sin cursor.

EXECUTE provando15 34,2,'key05','2015-07-22'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the word Execute and it will work.

```
$query = $this->db->query(
      "verificacion_fechas '".$codigo."',".$estado.",'".$llave_maestra."','".$fecha_actual."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample on how to call a MYSQL STORED PROCEDURE in codeigniter

```
$this->db->query('CALL procedure_name());
```

Comment: yeah, because that's how we call SP in CI.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

first way(if you do not use a variable);

```
$query=$this->MSSQL->query("EXEC ProcedureName");
```

second way(if you use a variable);

```
$query =$this->MSSQL->query("EXEC ProcedureName '$var1','$var2','$var3' ");
```

or

```
$query =$this->MSSQL->query("EXEC ProcedureName @varName1='$var1',@varName2='$var2',@varName3='$var3' ");
```

Note:if you get result like empty array add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to after BEGIN in your procedure.