# How to call MSSQL Stored Procedure with parameters in Codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure in my Codeigniter website, but I can't, I tried many solution but I couldn't.
I use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and Codeigniter 3.1 and sqlsrv dirver and iis 8.5 and php 5.6

my stored procedure code:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[count_message]
        @username smallint


AS  SET NOCOUNT ON;

return isnull((select count(*) from dbo.message where ms_user=1 or ms_user=@username),0)
```

Comment: better add tag php

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT or RETURN instead of OUTPUT](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output)

Comment: try to replace return statement to select, idk

Comment: Not an answer to your question but the ISNULL in your query will never return the second argument. This is because your query is a COUNT of rows that meet the predicates in your where clause and if no rows are returned it will return 0.

Comment: I do not get any things and not 0

Comment: Count will ALWAYS return a value. Try this. Select count(*) from sys.tables where name = 'asdfasdfadfasdf'. It will return 0, not null because it is known how many rows meet that criteria.

Comment: without isnull just return 0 in sql server execute stored procedure

Comment: If you execute count_message in SMS does it return anything besides 0? If you change it to `return @username` (instead of @num) does $result = 2600 so you know CI is passing it right?

Comment: I executed count_message in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and return number of message but when I use this stored procedure in CI don't get any result  $result = $this->db->query("exec count_message @username='2600'");
echo 'row Num: '.$result;

Comment: Maybe try calling it with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30425271/3585500)? Like `$sp = 'count_message'; $params = array('username' => 2600); $result = $this->db->query($sp, $params);`

Comment: Meant `$sp = 'count_message ?';` above. (Won't let me edit comment.)

Comment: [Or there's this answer where you just drop the `exec`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31586592/3585500) As in, `$result = $this->db->query("count_message '2600'");`

Comment: I checked $result = $this->db->query("count_message '2600'"); this method execute procedure but dont return any result, for example if i want to update or delete this method is good, but when I want to return a value I can't get any value in CI, please help me

Comment: please help me helllllpppppppppppp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Use this code and works very well

```
$result = $this->db->query("SE_Export_Top_Post N'{$searchId}', N'{$search}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->query("exec count_message @username='example'")
```

Comment: Not Return Any thing

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15434227)

Comment: @prava A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my codes but I couldn't get any output

I changed my stored procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[count_message]
        @username smallint,
        @num Int = NULL output

--AS    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 as
   begin

   set @num = isnull((select count(*) 
                      from dbo.sd_message 
                      where ms_user=1 or ms_user=@username),0)

   return @num

END
GO
```

and use this code in PHP/Codeigniter:

```
$result = $this->db->query("exec count_message @username='2600'");
echo 'row Num: '.$result;
```

Comment: If you have an Update to the question, please **edit** the question instead of writing an answer.

Comment: $result here will be an stdClass, which is converted to an empty string when you try to concatenate it.